# Unwanted comma-splitting when binding string (from inputText) to List<String> in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm working with Spring Web, my JSP has a inputText that I bind to List because I could set many inputText. 
The problem is that if I have a inputText with something like "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss,SSS". I got a list with two elements: "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss" and "SSS", when I would like to get just one with all the text. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of how the binding in Spring works. if you have just one input, and have a value containing commas for that input, Spring will convert this into a list of values for that attribute.

Suppose you have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields" value="Hi, SO">
```

The mapping in the DTO for the attribute `List<String> fields` will be set to ["Hi", "SO"].

To overcome this, you can have an extra empty input for that field just before the ones containing the actual values.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields" value="">
```

This will set the values in `fields` to ["", "Hi, SO"] and you can handle the empty string in your logic accordingly.